# MsBuild Very Slow in iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, msbuild

I have a script to launch the build of a xamarin ios app. Compilation is very slow, and it stops for a long time in the next part.

```
......
_ParseExtraMtouchArgs:
        NoSymbolStrip Output: False
        NoDSymUtil Output: false
```

How can I speed up the build?

Comment: "Slow?, compared to what" is my normal response... As a start, enable MSBuild diagnostic level debugging (or use `/detailedsummary` but there is a lot of "noise" to filter using that, I at least start with the Target and Task Performance Summary of the diag level logging) to obtain time metrics of each build task and then you can compare the speed of the various tasks/targets. From there; disk IO ops, cpu, and memory (in that order from my experience) should be looked at (on macOS, Activity Monitor is a good place to start.)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the server? Building on a local machine?

Ultimately, both have a similar problem. You can only compile to iOS on Apple. That is part of the licensing. If you are on your own machine, it means linking to a Mac and then creating the packages for the device/emulator. Visual Studio makes it easy, but it still takes a long time.

Since you say MSBuild, it could be on a server. But you still have a lot of the same issues. To compile to Apple, legally, you need an Apple machine with the compiler on it.

From a dev standpoint, I separate out the mobile app in its own solution and only work with it on my Mac. I have parallels and windows to fire up the back end services and SQL database. I keep the code in a directory on the Mac "side" but have different solutions handling different projects in the repo. It works fine. I do have a solution for my PC, but I have found the compilation is a royal PITA, so I have given up working on the Surface except when I am embroiled on web and backend stuff.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.
The build is launched from a Windows computer, passing the arguments of the mac connection to the MSBuild. The mac is a physical equipment.